Assigning a color based on the value in a matched cell
I want to auto-colour a scheduling spreadsheet, so each staff gets a unique colour, that can be updated easily with new staff etc.
The cells in column C of Staff have RGB values saved like this: RGB(123, 123, 123)
The cells range (i5:AN21) (for testing, normally i5:NJ1000) in Schedule are filled with initials (or blanks) that align with the initials in Column D of Staff.
The line:
Set colorPick = staffSheet.Cells(cellColorMatch, 3).Value

appears to consistently give

Run time error '13' Type Mismatch

If I put an RGB value directly into cell.interior.color it works and updates the sheet.
eg.
cell.interior.Color = RGB(255, 125, 194)

I can't get the colorPick variable to pass that value across as it mismatch errors.
Sub ColorCellsBasedOnText()

  Dim staffSheet As Worksheet, scheduleSheet As Worksheet
  Dim colorRange As Range, textRange As Range, cell As Range

  ' Set your sheets with color hex codes and text strings
  Set staffSheet = Sheets("Staff")
  Set scheduleSheet = Sheets("Schedule")

  ' Get last row with data (assuming RGB codes in column C and text strings in D)
Set colorRange = staffSheet.Range("C2:C" & staffSheet.Range("C2").End(xlUp).Row)

  ' Set range to color in the schedule sheet (I5:NJ1000)
  Set textRange = scheduleSheet.Range("I5:AN21")

  For Each cell In textRange
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
      Debug.Print "Current cell value:", cell.Value ' Print current text string

      ' Find matching text string row
      cellColorRow = Application.Match(Trim(cell.Value), staffSheet.Range("D2:D100" & colorRange.Rows.Count), vbBinaryCompare)
      cellColorMatch = cellColorRow + 1
      Debug.Print "Matching row found:", cellColorRow  ' Print matched row (if any)

      If Not IsError(cellColorRow) Then
      
       ' cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic ' Clear any existing color formatting
            
            Debug.Print "Applying color from row:", cellColorMatch  ' Print row used for color
            Debug.Print "Color value:", staffSheet.Cells(cellColorMatch, 3).Value
            Debug.Print "Cell Changing column:", cell.Column
            Debug.Print "Colour Code:", RGB(255, 125, 194)
            
       Set colorPick = staffSheet.Cells(cellColorMatch, 3).Value
        
            Debug.Print "Cell Colour Pick:", colorPick
            Debug.Print "cell Interior Color:", cell.Interior.Color

        cell.Interior.Color = colorPick
        
      End If
    End If
  Next cell
  
End Sub


Try it without the word Set. Also, it looks like you did not define what type of variable colorPick is.

Instead of using a separate column storing RGB values it might be easier to color the cells containing the staff initials?  Then you can pick up the color from the matched cells.

I tried removing set and defining the variable as long and string; I still got the error. If i change the RGB codes in excel to the 8 digit index colours it works fine; I could colour the cells and copy that colour as per your explanation as well! thanks

Instead of using a separate column storing RGB values it might be easier to color the cells containing the staff initials? Then you can pick up the color from the matched cells.
Sub ColorCellsBasedOnText()

    Dim staffSheet As Worksheet, scheduleSheet As Worksheet
    Dim colorRange As Range, textRange As Range, cell As Range, v As String, m
    
    Set staffSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Staff")
    Set scheduleSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Schedule")
    
    ' cells with initials, colored as needed
    Set colorRange = staffSheet.Range("D2:D" & _
                       staffSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Set textRange = scheduleSheet.Range("I5:AN21") 'range to be checked
    textRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone '? any clear previous fill ?

    'loop over cells to be colored
    For Each cell In textRange.Cells
        v = Trim(cell.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then   'any content?
            m = Application.Match(v, colorRange, 0)
            'if got match then set fill color
            If Not IsError(m) Then cell.Interior.Color = _
                          colorRange.Cells(m).Interior.Color
        End If
    Next cell
  
End Sub

Staff listing:

Schedule:

